# Only one array without a size allowed per struct?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010

I was writing a struct to describe a constant value I needed, and noticed something strange.

```
namespace res{
    namespace font{
        struct Structure{
            struct Glyph{
                int x, y, width, height, easement, advance;
            };
            int glyphCount;
            unsigned char asciiMap[];   // <-- always generates an error
            Glyph glyphData[];          // <-- never generates an error
        };
        const Structure system = {95, 
                              {
                                 // mapping data
                              }, 
                              {
                                 // glyph spacing data
                              }
        }; // system constructor
    } // namespace font
} // namespace res
```

The last two members of `Structure`, the unsized arrays, do not stop the compiler if they are by themselves.  But if they are *both* included in the struct's definition, it causes an error, saying the "type is incomplete"

This stops being a problem if I give the first array a size.  Which isn't a problem in this case, but I'm still curious...

My question is, why can I have one unsized array in my struct, but two cause a problem?

Comment: Unsigned arrays as struct members doesn't make sense. What  would `sizeof(Structure)` be?

Comment: @Pubby isn't that just a pointer?

Comment: @Pubby - It mustn't be too nonsensical, because it compiles without any issue if it's by itself.  I assume (and intend) the member to only point at the array literals I stuck in the constructor though.  It itself shouldn't do anything beyond that.

Comment: @WhozCraig: You seem to be using a cracked C++11 standard. I think you meant C11.

Comment: @Pubby: Usually, the structure is treated as if the incomplete array doesn't exist, so `sizeof(Structure)` is the size of everything except the array. But if you've allocated `sizeof(Structure) + N*sizeof(Glyph)` bytes of memory, then you can treat it as an array of size `N`. (This is in C; none of this is defined in standard C++).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In standard C++, you can't do this at all, although some compilers support it as an extension.

In C, every member of a `struct` needs to have a fixed position within the `struct`. This means that the *last* member can have an unknown size; but nothing can come after it, so there is no way to have more than one member of unknown size.

If you do take advantage of your compilers non-standard support for this hack in C++, then beware that things may go horribly wrong if any member of the `struct` is non-trivial. An object can only be "created" with a non-empty array at the end by allocating a block of raw memory and reinterpreting it as this type; if you do that, no constructors or destructors will be called.

Comment: Oh, I had no idea it was an extension... I suppose `char member[]` doesn't mean what I wanted it to mean then, if it needs to allocate the memory; I merely want it to point at an array literal.  Whoops!

Comment: @Clairvoire: Yes, if you want a pointer then declare a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a [*non-standard microsoft extension*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6fae073.aspx). C11 (note: C, not C++) allows the last array in a structure to be unsized (read: a *maximum* of one arrays):

> A Microsoft extension allows the last member of a C or C++ structure or class to be a variable-sized array. These are called unsized arrays. The unsized array at the end of the structure allows you to append a variable-sized string or other array, thus avoiding the run-time execution cost of a pointer dereference.
>
> ```
> // unsized_arrays_in_structures1.cpp
> // compile with: /c
> struct PERSON {
>    unsigned number;
>    char name[];   // Unsized array
> };
> ```
>
> If you apply the sizeof operator to this structure, the ending array size is considered to be 0. The size of this structure is 2 bytes, which is the size of the unsigned member. To get the true size of a variable of type PERSON, you would need to obtain the array size separately.
>
> The size of the structure is added to the size of the array to get the total size to be allocated. After allocation, the array is copied to the array member of the structure, as shown below:

Answer (score 2):

The compiler needs to be able to decide on the offset of every member within the struct. That's why you're not allowed to place *any* further members after an unsized array. It follows from this that you can't have two unsized arrays in a struct.

Comment: and don't forget you can't have any unsized array in standard C++.

Answer (score 1):

It is an [extension from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6fae073.aspx), and `sizeof(structure) == sizeof(structure_without_variable_size_array)`.

I guess they use the initializer to find the size of the array. If you have two variable size arrays, you can't find it (equivalent to find one unique solution of a 2-unknown system with only 1 equation...)

Answer (score 1):

Arrays without a dimension are not allowed in a `struct`,
period, at least in C++.  In C, the *last* member (and only the
last) may be declared without a dimension, and some compilers
allow this in C++, as an extension, but you shouldn't count on
it (and in strict mode, they should at least complain about it).
Other compilers have implemented the same semantics if the last
element had a dimension of 0 (also an extension, requiring
a diagnostic in strict mode).

The reason for limiting incomplete array types to the last
element is simple: what would be the offset of any following
elements?  Even when it is the last element, there are
restrictions to the use of the resulting struct: it cannot be
a member of another struct or an array, for example, and
`sizeof` ignores this last element.